# How do I get two instances of "Command Prompt with Ruby"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-prompt

I am an absolute beginner with Ruby on Rails and I seem to have a problem with the way I should be doing things.

If I use "rails server" in order to be able to test my application, I can't do anything else in the command line.

Is there another way of doing scaffolding, other than command line? If not, how to I get two "Command prompts with Ruby" at the same time?

Comment: Doesn't work, tried it. It just highlights the one that I have opened in the first place.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8 Pro

Comment: ... Probably need to bone up on Win8 then; you can open multiple terminals. http://commandwindows.com/windows-8-commands.htm

Answer (score 0):

When you search for it from your metro screen, right click on it and then click on `Open in a new window`.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal tab before you start your Rails server, and then you can just leave it running in the background.  However, do make sure you go back to that tab and specifically shut the server down before closing terminal as it doesn't always automatically shut down when terminal is closed and then you may have problems when reopening later.